# ID/Magnetic Card Reader using audio jack for Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-8, windows-8.1, point-of-sale

Does anyone know of a magnetic card reader that works with the audio jack for a Windows 8.1 tablet device? (this is to read employee ID cards, not credit cards).

Are there any more (tablet/mobile) innovative solutions than to use ID magnetic cards for Windows 8.1?

I guess I can have a centralized terminal where employees go to identify themselves and unlock their POS tablets until logged off/timeout (there I can go from simple to fancy with ID card readers, finger print readers, palm vein readers, etc.), but I would love to hear any other methods.

Answer (score 1):

I know of USB ones that will work with Windows 8.1 tablets (they also work with the Store apps), but I don't know of any that work with the audio jack unfortunately. As there is no exposed API for the audio jack, I don't believe it is possible.

This device claims to work with Windows 8.1 however: [Rambler 3.0](https://www.tasq.com/products/mobile-pos-systems/anywhere-commerce/rambler-3-0/)

Having not tested it, I can't tell you whether its a worthwhile investment.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can take a look at [magnetic card reader](http://www.syncotek.com/product/card_reader_1.html) Syncotek SC-750, it has RS-232 interface, baud rate adjustable; USB port and TTL at optional. And operation responded by two LEDs and buzzer.